# nodejs server app.post issue XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: http://localhost:3000/get_messages Line Number 1, Column 1:

Tags: mysql, node.js, http

I followed a tutorial on YouTube to create a private user to user chat.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ozrm_xftcjQ

Everything on the chat works accept that i keep getting this Error:

```
XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: http://localhost:3000/get_messages Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

using firefox developer edition and chrome. if i click the stack trace link i get the following xml error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /get_messages</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

but i have no GET calls at all..

The code looks as follows:

server.js file

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
//creating express instance
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//creating http instance
var http = require("http").createServer(app);

//app.use(express.static(__dirname));

//creating socket instance
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

//create body parser instance
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//enable url encode for POST requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }));

//create instance of mysql
var mysql = require('mysql');

//create mysql connection
//          connectionLimit: 100,debug: true
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'chatio'
});    

connection.connect(function(error){
if(error){
console.log(error);
return;
}
console.log('database connected');
})

//enable header request for post requests
app.use(function(request, result, next){
result.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
next();
})

//create api to return all messages
app.post("/get_messages", function(request, result){
console.log(request);
console.log(result);
connection.query("SELECT * FROM chat_messages WHERE (`from_id` = '"+request.body.sender+"' AND   `to_id` = '"+request.body.receiver+"') OR (`from_id` = '"+request.body.receiver+"' AND `to_id` = '"+request.body.sender+"')", function(error, messages){
if(error){
console.log(error);
return;
}
console.log(messages);
//response will be in JSON
result.end(JSON.stringify(messages));
});    
})    

io.on("connection", function(socket){
socket.on("send_message", function(data){
//send event to receiver
var socketId = users[data.receiver];

io.to(socketId).emit("new_message", data);

//save in database
connection.query("INSERT INTO chat_messages (`from_id`,`to_id`,`message`) VALUES ('"+data.sender+"', '"+data.receiver+"', '"+data.message+"')", function(error, result){

if(error){
console.log(error);
return;
}
console.log('message saved');
});    
})    
})

http.listen(port, function(){
console.log("server started");
})
```

inde.php file code as follows:

```
//creating io connection
var io = io("http://localhost:3000");

var receiver = "johnny";
var sender = "steven";


function onUserSelected(){
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost:3000/get_messages",
method:"POST",
cache: false,
data: {
"sender" : sender,
"receiver" : receiver
},
dataType: "json",
success: function(response){
var messages = response; //JSON.parse();
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
html += "<li>" +messages[i].from_id + " says: " + messages[i].message + "</li>";
document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += html;
}
}
});
return;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i figured it out..

the problem comes from this line:

```
result.end(JSON.stringify(messages));
```

I dont exactly understand why, but i changed it to

```
result.send(JSON.stringify(messages));
```

and now the bug is gone